# Cross-document references in the pdf

Tags: javascript, pdf, document, pdf.js

How to create the cross-document reference on the pdf level? Does the format support something like that? Is it possible?

I see, that LaTeX supports the similar feature, for example: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14364/cross-referencing-between-different-files

We're planning to customize the Pdf.js for this, but the question is how to implement references between two and more documents: https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/
Backend: Django, like in MIT nb project: https://github.com/nbproject

The context of what we'd like to accomplish: you can select a region in the pdf (or the text fragment, but in pdf and djvu the content is often a scan of the document), create a node in the graph for term we're interested in, relate it to the region, write in it the metadata, the nominal time of mastering the concept in the chapter of the textbook, connect with other nodes/regions either across other textbooks or within the current one, and allow user to navigate from one region to another like with the regular URL, by clicking on the region and transferring to the referenced one. If there are multiple references from one node/region, we allow user to choose, which one he'd like to be transferred to.

[image]

Comment: First of all, try using simple `<a>`s to make links to `#id`-ed elements. For areas on image try `<area>` tags

Comment: You want to adds a hyperlink, correct - adobe.com/acrobat/hub/how-to/add-hyperlink-to-pdf?   How are you generating your PDF's?

Comment: @MrSmith no, we need a meta-layer, where we keep the annotated clickable regions (rectangles with coordinates). And one region, being clicked, can either transfer us to the next region or let us choose where we'd like to be transferred to. And targeted region may lie as in the limits of the document as lead to another region in another document.